# THREE.IcosahedronGeometry has no vertices array

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was following Advanced Creative Coding with WebGL & Shaders course https://frontendmasters.com/courses/webgl-shaders/
by Matt DesLauriersd and one video he extracted the vertices array for icosahedronGeometry object
by doing this:

```
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 16);
  const baseGeometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(1, 1);


  const points = baseGeometry.vertices;
  console.log(points)
```

but when I do it, it's undefined

link to jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/18hd3jge/

Answer (score 4):

The tutorial is outdated. Since `r125` all geometry generators like `SphereGeometry` produce `BufferGeometry`. The same release also removed the former `Geometry` from the library.

If you want to access the vertices of a buffer geometry, you have to work with the `position` buffer attribute. Typical code for this looks like so:

```js
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 16);
const positionAttribute = geometry.getAttribute( 'position' );

const vertex = new THREE.Vector3();

for ( let vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < positionAttribute.count; vertexIndex ++ ) {

    vertex.fromBufferAttribute( positionAttribute, vertexIndex );

    // now do something with vertex

}
```

More information about the removal of `Geometry` here: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-geometry-will-be-removed-from-core-with-r125/22401